# in App purchase showing "Environment Sandbox" even after status changed to "ready for sale"

Tags: iphone, itunes, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

My iPhone application  and in App purchase  status become "ready for Sale" yesterday. But when am running my In App Purchase , i am getting "[Environment Sandbox]" in "Do you want to buy .... push notifications"  .How can i change my in app purchase from test environment ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your app is getting "resigned" with a different certificate when it gets processed for the AppStore so it won't use the Sandbox after a user downloads it from the AppStore.